# MySql multiple join on same table - get ending balance of multiple ledgers/wallets

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, performance, join

`transactions` table schema:

```
--------------------------------------
| user_id | currency | amount | date |
--------------------------------------
|       1 |      eur |    500 | ...  |
|       1 |      gbp |    100 | ...  |
|       1 |      usd |     10 | ...  |
|       1 |      usd |     10 | ...  |
|       1 |      gbp |    100 | ...  |
|       1 |      usd |     10 | ...  |
|       1 |      usd |     10 | ...  |
|       2 |      jpy |     99 | ...  |
|       1 |      jpy |     99 | ...  |
--------------------------------------
```

What I want:

```
-----------------------------------
|         | total balances        |
| user_id | eur | usd | gbp | jpy |
-----------------------------------
|       1 | 500 |  40 | 200 |  99 |
|       2 |   0 |   0 |   0 |  99 |
-----------------------------------
```

My Query Code (using Laravel's Eloquent ORM):

```
$query = DB::table('users AS u')
    ->join ('transactions AS t1', 't1.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->where('t1.currency', 'eur')
    ->join ('transactions AS t2', 't2.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->where('t2.currency', 'usd')
    ->join ('transactions AS t3', 't3.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->where('t3.currency', 'gbp')
    ->join ('transactions AS t4', 't4.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->where('t4.currency', 'jpy')
    ->selectRaw('
        u.id AS u_id,
        u.username AS u_username,
        SUM(t1.amount) AS total_eur,
        SUM(t2.amount) AS total_usd,
        SUM(t3.amount) AS total_gbp,
        SUM(t4.amount) AS total_jpy
    ')
    ->groupBy('u.id');

dd($query->get());
```

Resulting SQL:

```
select 
      SUM(t1.amount) AS total_eur,
      SUM(t2.amount) AS total_gbp,
      SUM(t3.amount) AS total_usd,
      SUM(t4.amount) AS total_jpy,
      u.id AS u_id,
      u.username AS u_username
      
   from `users` as `u` 
   left join `transactions` as `t1` on `t1`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
   left join `transactions` as `t2` on `t2`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
   left join `transactions` as `t3` on `t3`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` 
   left join `transactions` as `t4` on `t4`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` 
   
   where `t1`.`wallet_type` = 'eur'
     and `t2`.`wallet_type` = 'gbp'
     and `t3`.`wallet_type` = 'usd'
     and `t3`.`wallet_type` = 'jpy'

   group by `u`.`id`
```

It is **very slow** when using 3 or more joins (`transactions` table has only ~600 rows)
When I only use two currencies / only two joins, it is quite fast (under 1 second)

I think joining the same table multiple times is a bad practice.
Is there any way to optimize the query?

Comment: ah, so I just need to `join transactions` only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like

```
$query = DB::table('users AS u')
    ->join ('transactions AS t1', 't1.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->selectRaw('
        u.id AS u_id,
        u.username AS u_username,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t1.currency = \'eur\' THEN t1.amount END) AS total_eur,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t1.currency = \'usd\' THEN t1.amount END) AS total_usd,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t1.currency = \'gbp\' THEN t1.amount END) AS total_gbp,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t1.currency = \'jpy\' THEN t1.amount END) AS total_jpy
    ')
    ->groupBy('u.id');
```

Check syntax - I do not use Laravel.

If some currency is not listed in some user data you'll get NULL. If you need zero then extend the expressions till `CASE WHEN t1.currency = \'xxx\' THEN t1.amount ELSE 0 END`

Comment: Just updated my code, works like a charm, thanks a lot!